# .js ScrollTop to div or section tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script that allows me to add an anchor-link with a `.class` attached to my HTML document, which would then scroll the user to a position on the webpage when clicked on.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="about-scroll">About</li>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.about-scroll').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 646
    }, 1600);

    return false;
});
```

---

This works fine, however, as the content isn't always static (drop-down accordions, a responsive layout etc.), how would I be able to scroll to a specific `#div` or `section` tag rather than a numeric value on the page?

**Example:**

```
<div class="about">
    <h3>About</h3>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div> <!-- end .about -->
```

Comment: Why not use # anchors? [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the `h3` an `id`, say header. Then, you would reference the click event by using `href="#header"`

HTML

```
<h3 id="hi">HIIIIII</h3>
<a href="#hi">Scroll to Top</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();                 // prevents default action of <a>
  var target = this.hash,             // gets the href of the <a>
      $target = $(target);            // puts it as a selector
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top // scrolls to the top of the element clicked on
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeP3V/)

The great thing about this function is that it is reuseable

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with no animation you can go with the answer which says just give the element you want to go to an ID and reference it with href="#the_id_you_placed"

for animation, you can still use the ID, but find the offset and animate to there:

```
$('.about-scroll').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#the_id_you_placed').offset().top
    }, 1600);

    return false;
});
```